# What speed must rotate a space station to provide an Earth-like gravity

Tags: science-based, physics

With what speed must a space station of 60m radius rotate to produce at its outer rim an artificial gravity equal to true gravity(as on the surface of earth)?
keep in mind that the space station produce the gravity of 9.8m/sec.sec..

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding. I am afraid your question is very much out of scope for this StackExchange. However the answer is: 4 revolutions per minute.

Comment: At which point many people would get the heaves.

Answer (score 4):

The acceleration equation is : [image] with `gamma : acceleration (m.s^-2), v : speed (m.s^-1), r : radius (m), omega : rotational speed (s^-1)`

Here you want `gamma = 1g = 9.8 m.s^-1` and `r = 60m`

So [image]. Which results in w (omega) = 0.4041 rad.s^-1 = **3.86 tr/min**